# What is the Julia set of

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $M:\mathbb{C^2}\mapsto\mathbb{C^2}$ be given as
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
     e^{i\theta} & 0 \\
     0          & 1   
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
What is its Julia set? First off is it non-empty. What is its Hausdorff measure? Does taking $\theta$ rational or irrational make any difference?

Comment: What is giving you trouble with this?

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is trivial?

Comment: No. I am only asking a question.  If I had meant to say that the problem was trivial, it would look like this:  “The problem is trivial.”